# ASP.NET MVC Removed Controller QueryString Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

When I use the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // 
"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

The app finds the method below:

```
public ActionResult News(DateTime? FromDate, DateTime? ToDate)
{
    IList<Model.MonthGroupNewsEntry> monthGroupNewsEntries = new services.NewsEntryService(new Data.SqlNewsEntryRepository()).GetMonthGroupNewsEntries();
    IList<Model.NewsEntry> newsEntries = new Services.NewsEntryService(new Data.SqlNewsEntryRepository()).GetNewsEntriesWithinDateRange(FromDate, 
    return View(new Models.NewsViewModel(monthGroupNewsEntries, newsEntries));
}
```

From:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(b.MonthName + " " + b.Year.ToString() +  " (" + b.EntryCount.ToString() + ")", "News", new { FromDate = b.FromDate, ToDate = b.ToDate}) %>
```

But when I attempt to remove the controller from the url using below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default",
"{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

I get a 404 resource not found error.

*Note* : The other methods in the class work fine but these either have no parameters or "id", it's only the method that's called with the two DateTime? parameters that fails when I remove the controller from the URL.

Thanks for the updated answer, however - the only change I make is to remove the "{controller}/" text from the "routes.MapRoute" in the above - there is no chance of any spelling mistake etc., this is also using MVC 3.

*Further* : using Charx's suggestion:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"SpecificAction",
"{action}/{FromDate}/{ToDate}",
new { controller = "ControllerName", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

I no longer get a 404 error, but it gave a "400 - bad request" due to the '/'s in the date, so I reformatted the date as dd-MM-YYYY:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(b.MonthName + " " + b.Year.ToString() +  " (" + b.EntryCount.ToString() + ")", "News", new { FromDate = b.FromDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), ToDate = b.ToDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}) %>
```

It no longer 404's, the FromDate is recognised fine but the ToDate comes through as null.

*Final* : I changed the type of the two dates to strings and cast them to datetime in the method - now both parameters come through fine - I guess it was perhaps looking for the time element of the first parameter and therefore ignored the second.

Only outstanding thing now is that the methods requiring an "id" parameter now seems to use it as a querystring (NewsEnrty?ID=5) rather than "NewsEntry/5" if anyone can answer this then thanks - otherwise question answered - thanks again Chanx.

Comment: Why are you removing `{controller}` from your mapped route? Are you trying to just make a two-levels deep URL?

Comment: The site is very simple - having the controller in the url seems excessive as there will only ever be one controller - can it not just be removed from the url but still used in routing to ascertain the necessary class?

Comment: Take a look at my answer and let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited. If you want to still be able to identify the action to call in your URL, then you must specify your Specific Action route and be sure to identify the correct Controller the actions are on:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"SpecificAction",
"{action}/{FromDate}/{ToDate}",
new { controller = "ControllerName", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );

routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // 
"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

Comment: Thanks but WhatIWantURLDirToBe is "nothing", I don't want a URL dir, I do however want an action which appears to be missing above.  When I try your solution I get a 404 immediately on the Index page.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining myself very well, the route which just has {action}/{id} works perfectly for Index and any method with an "id" parameter - it results in a 404 when the method has the two DateTime? parameters - the only different between the methods is that the DateTime? parameter methods result in a querystring type "?from=xxxxx&to=xxxxx" rather than the standard "/xxxxx" type mvc url.  All methods work perfectly with "{controller}/{action}/{id}" when I remove "{controller}/" only the method with the DateTime? parameters fail.

Comment: Right. The explaining part is missing. Edited answer, I hope it's getting closer to what you need.

Comment: Nearly - but I see where you're going now - the '/'s in the date cause a 400 "bad request" - perhaps I should reformat the date into YYYYMMDD for the call to get rid of the '/'s then your solution should work.

Comment: @user1907097 Add a new mapped route with `{action}/{id}`. be sure to name it something other than `"SpecificAction"` and identify the controller, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, when you edit your question I get the initial answer you want to have. I also create simple solution to test your problem and it works well also for News controller action. There are no way how dates could affect routing. But you need to check firstly - maybe you made some mistakes. Check for routing once again, chech controller name, retype it, chech that proper action placed n prpper controller. If you still will have the problem create a small project for your problem and putit on dropbox or somewhere else where I can get it and test, because for now I can't reproduce your issue. Also, I;m working with MVC 3.

Comment: Why wouldn't this use the controller specified in the last parameter to MapRoute, i.e. HomeController?

Comment: The site is very simple - having the controller in the url seems excessive as there will only ever be one controller - can it not just be removed from the url but still used in routing to ascertain the necessary class?Question editted above...